# Avoiding cyclic dependencies when using listeners

Tags: java, jface

What is the best way to avoid cyclic dependencies in this very simplistic example?  I would like to avoid inlining the SelectionChangedListener as it is a rather large/complex class.

```
class SomeGui extends Dialog {
    TreeViewer someWidget;
    SelectionChangedListener someListener;

    private void someMethod(){
        someListener = new SelectionChangedListener(this);
        someWidget.addSelectionChangedListener(someListener);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
    }
}

class SelectionChangedListener implements ISelectionChangedListener{
    SomeGui reference;

    public SelectionChangedListener(SomeGui reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        reference.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see an example I created here: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java FetcherListener is a static interface. Because the interface is public, any other class can implement this and register for updates from the DataFetcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you make the listener an 'inner' class of the dialog, then it has an implicit instance of the dialog:

```
class SomeGui extends Dialog {
    TreeViewer someWidget;
    ISelectionChangedListener someListener;

    private void someMethod() {
        someListener = new SelectionChangedListener();
        someWidget.addSelectionChangedListener(someListener);
    }

    void doSomething() {
    }

    private class SelectionChangedListener implements ISelectionChangedListener {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
           doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If you are using Java 8 this can be simplified to:

```
class SomeGui extends Dialog {
    TreeViewer someWidget;
    ISelectionChangedListener someListener;

    private void someMethod() {
        someListener = this::widgetSelectionChanged;
        someWidget.addSelectionChangedListener(someListener);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
    }

    private void widgetSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
       doSomething();
    }
```

}